# What do the different groovy shell verbosity levels mean?

Tags: groovy

`org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.IO` has four verbosity levels but doesn't make it very clear what they do. Which is the System default? 
What are the differences between them? The only thing I've noticed so far is that if Verbosity is set to quiet, Groovysh will not print the last returned statement in the shell...

```
package org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.IO

public static final Verbosity QUIET = new Verbosity("QUIET");

public static final Verbosity INFO = new Verbosity("INFO");

public static final Verbosity VERBOSE = new Verbosity("VERBOSE");

public static final Verbosity DEBUG = new Verbosity("DEBUG");
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the default is `INFO`, and it [is set here](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/tools/shell/util/Preferences.java).

And it looks like it's [used here to set the colour of the output](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/tools/shell/util/Logger.java) based on the Level.  However, I've only had a brief look and grep of the code, and may be wrong or have missed something.